# preposition used with mathematical operators

Tags: grammar

Is "minus with" or "minus by"correct? What preposition can be used for mathematical operator " multiply"?

Answer (score 2):

+ Summation:

- a + b | a plus b
- c = a + b | c is the sum **of** a and b
- c = a + b | add a **to** b to get c

- Subtraction:

- a - b  |  a minus b
- c = a - b | c is the difference **of** a and b
- c = a - b | subtract b **from** a to get c

* Multiplication:

- a * b   | a times b
- c = a * b | c is the multiplication **of** a and b
- c = a * b | multiply b **with** a to get c

/ Division:

- a / b  | a divided **by** b
- c = a / b | c is the quotient **of** a and b
- c = a / b | divide a **by** b to get c

Answer (score 1):

Just "minus." Six minus five is one. One could say "subtracted from" as in three subtracted from eight is five. Also, "multiplied by," as in two multiplied by two is four.