# What is the category name used for words describing mathematical operations?

Tags: grammar, terminology

Refer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/328687/127931) for more examples.

We have multiplication, which has "multiply" as the verb. But we say "a times b".

Similarly, we have division, which has "divide" as the verb.  But we say "a divided by b".

First, what is the category name of "plus," "minus," "times," and "divided by"? They aren't "operators" or "operations," nor are they strictly verbs. So, what are they?

Second, what is grammatical story there? When I write that kind of sentence, what am I creating? A phrase, a clause? Grammatically, what am I doing?

Comment: *"They aren't operators"*. They **are**, see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/operators) – 3a: something and especially a symbol that denotes or performs a mathematical or logical operation. 3b: a mathematical function.

Comment: "a divided by b" is a noun phrase. It's similar to "the car driven by Joe"

Comment: @Barmar Oh, rght. I would have said there's a passive verb.

Comment: They are prepositions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), *plus, minus,* and *times* are all prepositions (p. 635). *Divided* is likely best taken as an adjective rather than a verb form, since unlike the verb *to divide* it has a stative intepretation. It's an adjective that (in the sense in question) can only occur postpositively, and requires as a complement a prepositional phrase with the preposition *by.*

So "five plus three" is a noun phrase in which "five" is modified by the prepositional phrase "plus three"; the same applies to "five minus three" and "five times three." "Five divided by three," however, is a noun phrase in which "five" is modified by the adjective phrase "divided by three"; in turn, "divided by three" consists of the adjective "divided" with the prepositional phrase "by three" as a dependent of it.

Of course, in the mathematical expression "5 + 3" we don't see "+ 3" as somehow a dependent of "5". But as a matter of English syntax in "five plus three" the prepositional phrase "plus three" is a modifier of "five." Of course "five plus three" refers, not to some version of the number five, but to the number two, just as "a vase broken into pieces" typically refers, not to a vase, but to the pieces produced by breaking it.

Comment: The model 5 + 3 has two interpretations: 5 combined with 3 in the usual identity-retaining-of-elements sense (so you still have the 5 blue and 3 red marbles in the total of 8 marbles), or the transformation 5 increased by 3 (so the worm which once was 5cm long is now 8cm long; the 5 is history).

Comment: Where does *GGEL* call *divided* an adjective in this function? I would call it a verb in a passive construction.

Comment: @TinfoilHat They don't make any claims about that word; I would have cited a page number if they did. My reasoning is that *to divide* has a dynamic interpretation, whereas *divided* has a stative one, which is generally a test for verbal vs. adjectival passives.

Comment: Note also that we can't add a *by* phrase corresponding to the subject of the verb in this use of *divided*: "He divided six by two and got three" is valid, but not \*"Six divided by two by him was three."

Comment: 4 divides 12; 12 is divided by 4.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "4 divides 12" is a different sense of the word *divide* (meaning "12 is divisible by 4"); "12 divided by 5 is 2.4" does not entail that 12 is divisible by 5.

Comment: What is the sense of *divide* here? 5 divides 12; 12 is divided by 5.

Comment: @TinfoilHat In a sentence like "3 divides 9," "divides" means "be a divisor of without remainder" (see [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/divide)); that's the only sense of *divide* in which I've heard sentences like "3 divides 9" being used. That sense of *divide* is not being used in "12 divided by 5 is 2.4," since 5 does not divide 12.

Comment: If 12 can be divided by anything — 2, 3.14, 5... — it is dividable.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That is not what the word *divisible* means; see [Collins.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/divisible) Sure, you can say "12 was divided by 4 in the calculation," but again that has a dynamic rather than a stative interpretation (note that here you can add a *by*-phrase, e.g. "12 was divided by 4 by him") -- in that case it's a verbal passive, whereas here it's an adjectival one. See *CGEL* pp. 1436-1440.